# Ajax form submitting successfully but alert error showing up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I created an AJAX form that submits to a php page. This form is submitting successfully in terms of, I am getting the email address in my database and I have a confirmation email that sends out.

However, I am getting an alert message saying "Error|", so obviously it is coming from this:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
```

I am unsure of why an error is throwing if it works. Another thing, this form is reloading the page. I have `event.preventDefault();` in place, so why would the page be reloading?

I appreciate any help.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="email" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-input" placeholder="Your Email Address">
  <input type="submit" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        var newsletter_email = $("#footer-grid1-newsletter-input").val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "newsletterSend.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "newsletter_email": newsletter_email
            },
            success: function (data) {
            //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to insert email!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    /*$(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                    $(".announcement_success").show();
                    $('.announcement_success').html('Announcement Successfully Added!');
                    $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);*/
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });
    });
});

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$newsletter_email = $_POST['newsletter_email'];

try {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter (email, subscribed) VALUES (?, NOW())");
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $newsletter_email);
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
    $stmt->execute();
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            die('Newsletter email execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
 } catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: your missing an `event` on `.on("click", function () {...`  it should be `.on("click", function (event) {`

Comment: set the `dataType` and also send the `same type from php`

Comment: @guradio What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @roullie That did it. Now I just need to figure out how to clear the input field.

Comment: @Becky you can try to reset it.  `$("YOUR_FORM")[0].reset()`

Comment: @roullie Perfect, thanks! Feel free to create an answer. Do you know what guradio was referring to about the php?

Comment: @Becky answered below.  and about guradio.  i think he's talking about the `dataType` of the request..  Where your php should also be the same..  let's say `dataType: 'json'`  the your php should return a `json_encoded` item

Comment: @roullie Thanks. I am still a bit confused with what you mean. I somewhat understand, but why is my data types not the same? I am new to working with AJAX and not the best at php yet. Is my php even returning anything?

Comment: it depends on what you need.  in your example you don't need to set the `dataType`.  since you only return a string `"Error!"`.

Comment: @roullie Is there a way to return the prepared statement errors? Is that what I should be doing? Sorry for the questions, just trying to learn this the best I can.

Comment: Yes.  you already implemented it based on you code above.  :)

Comment: I am referring to sending it back to the console.

Comment: @Becky ohh. yes you can.  But it's better to do error handling on the backend not in client side

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event` doesn't have any reference

```
.on("click", function () {
```

should be

```
.on("click", function (event) {
```

Then clearing your form.  you can do

```
$("YOUR_FORM")[0].reset()
```